# Finding zeros using synthetic division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $X=2$ a zero of $P(x)$ $=x^3-x^2+3x-10$? Use synthetic division to support your answer.

Can someone please help explain how to do this.

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: The synthetic division process you learned in your previous question will do it. Divide by $x-2$. The remainder will be $0$.

Comment: Ok, using the process I just learned my remainder was 0 and my quotient is x^2+x+5. Now since 2 is no where in the quotient does that mean it is not a zero?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is,

$(x - 2)(x^2 + bx + c) = x^3 - x^2 + 3x - 10 \ \Rightarrow \ bx^2 - 2x^2 + cx - 2bx - 2c = - x^2 + 3x - 10$

Thus, $b - 2 = -1 \ \Rightarrow \ b = 1$ and $-2c = -10 \ \Rightarrow \ c = 5$.

Comment: This is better than the divison. Divison is ugly!

Answer (score 1):

If $x=2$ is a zero, then we can factor the polynomial as: $(x-2)(....)=x^3-x^2+3x-10=0$.

Now, we have to find out what that 'something' is:

We divide $x-2$ by $x^3-x^2+3x-10$ using synthetic divison:

[image]

That means that the second factor is: $x^2+x+5$, so we can rewrite the whole polynomial as: $(x-2)(x^2+x+5)$.

$$(x-2)(x^2+x+5)=x^3+x^2+5x-2x^2-2x-10$$

$$=x^3-x^2+3x-10$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: So then that makes 2 a zero of the polynomial?

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way according to your book, but I think so.